# springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0 . Unable to set default value in global request parameters

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springfox

I need to set the global request parameters in spring fox config docket with default value. I am using OAS 3.0. Below is the code for the same, I tried with setting as example too but not working.

```
private RequestParameter secretkey() {
        return new RequestParameterBuilder()
                .name("secretkey")
                .description("secretkey")
                .in(ParameterType.HEADER)
                .required(false)
                .query(q -> q.model(m -> m.scalarModel(ScalarType.STRING)).defaultValue("123"))
                .example(new ExampleBuilder().value("test").mediaType("application/text").externalValue("ex")
                        .description("desc").summary("summ").id("121").build())
                .hidden(true)
                .build();
    }
```